# bash strip line matching wildcard

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

```
sed -i -e "/^*google.com*/d" activedomains.txt
```

What I am trying to do is strip any line containing * google.com * it needs to be the wildcard on both front and rear, can't seem to figure it out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean this?

```
sed -i -e "/google\.com/d" activedomains.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` uses regex, not globbing (although maybe there is something that does).  Pretty simple to change, though:

```
sed -i '/google\.com/d' activedomains.txt
```

This deletes any line that *matches* `google.com`.  You could also use

```
sed -i -e '/^.*google.com.*/d' activedomains.txt
```

...which is more and line with what you were doing and literally means "the start of the string, then zero or more of any character followed by 'google (one of any character) com' followed by zero or more of any character."  Of course, since it is surrounded by "zero or mores," it's just as well to match it directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should works :

```
sed -i -e "/google.com/d" activedomains.txt
```

No need wildcard here : it's like a `grep`